# Lifespan of code loaded with nashorn.eval(file/string)

Tags: java, nashorn

Consider following:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager(null); // Why not passing null results in later "nashorn" return null?
this.engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

File scriptsDir = IOUtils.getScriptDir(); // some file
File[] scripts = scriptsDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".js");
    }
});

for (File script : scripts) // Loop all
{
    try
    {
        // basically I want to evaluate all script files and pull "QuestHolder" object from them.
        this.engine.eval(new FileReader(script));

        Object o = this.engine.get("qh"); // get "QuestHolder" object.

        if (o instanceof QuestHolder)
        {
            QuestManager.register((QuestHolder) o);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ScriptException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here are 2 .js examples:

/dir/quest1.js:

```
var QuestHolder = Java.type('example.quest.QuestHolder');
var qh = new QuestHolder("Save the christmas!");
```

/dir/quest2.js:

```
var QuestHolder = Java.type('example.quest.QuestHolder');
var qh = new QuestHolder("Get all the presents!");
```

I'd like to know more about internals.

1. How long does object ("qh" in this case) exists? Is it the same as Java's reference (GC)?
2. Is it safe to assume that when I am evaluating every next script, everything from previous file is 100% "lost" (for one I noticed that "qh" in both scripts don't collide like I think they would in JS)?

3.1. What about those objects I pulled out ("this.engine.get("qh")")? Do they now exist ONLY on Java App's side?

3.2. How does it work in case of functions or JS class extensions that I'd generate with script? (I am referring to making sub-classes of Java classes from within the script, e.g: extend QuestHolder and override some method, then .get it and register in my QuestManager as custom-class object).

Overally - I want to understand as much internals as I can so that I won't get any surprises.

4. If evaluating (point 2) next script would mean that previous evaluation is lost, is it possible, and how, to create "shared" evaluation for all scripts to use? I'd like to declare global Java.type('') for all quests to use, so that you don't have to type:

   var QuestHolder = Java.type('example.quest.QuestHolder');

...and many more whenever you make new file.

5. I belive it is possilbe (I think I read it somewhere) to make nashorn only have access to predefined types (Java.type('')). Is it? I'd like to make my scripts only have access to API stuff, not game internals.

Thank you for any links and/or explanations.

Answer (score 0):

A script engine caches compiled Class objects. Script functions are alive with usual GC rules -- as long as there is some transitive link reachable from another live object. So, Java.type's is alive as long as you've reference to it from some script function invocation using it.

You can filter script access to Java types using nashorn specific API jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ClassFilter ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ClassFilter.html )